# Is there an API for comments submitted to Google Classroom announcements?

Tags: google-classroom

In the Google Classroom API, I can't find an API that returns the comments students post on teacher announcements.

CourseWorkSubmissions only return submissions of Assignments and Questions.

Is there any Google Classroom API that returns comments on teacher announcements?

Comment: I think its a limitation of the Classroom API. Since you cannot find any comment related field in the [Resource: Announcement](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements#resource-announcement) response body specified.

Comment: I am looking for this too, not answer from google yet.

Comment: Did you find out anything?

Comment: The same question exists in Google support, unanswered yet however: https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/thread/48137272?hl=en

Comment: If Google doesn't have an official API for this, you might want to try and find it yourself. When you visit the website with the comments, press F12 in your browser and switch to "Network", then reload the comments(/website) and there you can see every site that has been called. Maybe there is an API you can utilize. Google's stuff is pretty hardened, so even if you know which API to call it might be difficult to get it to work actually.

Comment: @jonii Google's responses in general are awful, but [Google Classroom's API is even worse](https://pastebin.com/B9mGNGSV).